# How can I enable “Sleep Mode” from iOS Shortcuts

Tags: ios, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I’ve got an iOS Shortcut that sets my alarm and turns off my lights but I also want it to turn on “Sleep Mode” on my iPhone and Apple Watch. This can manually be done by clicking the bed icon labelled “Sleep Mode” in the Control Panel (see pic below) but I can’t for the life of me find how to do this using a shortcut. I can disable it in the morning with a shortcut when I cancel my alarm by turning off DND mode but turning on DND doesn’t turn on the rest of Sleep Mode.

Anyone have any idea how to enable this from an iOS Shortcut?

[image]

Comment: Not your scenario - but some good ideas here https://www.smallbites.me/creating-ios14-wind-down-shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

The ability to turn Sleep mode on or off has been added to Shortcuts in iOS 15.

When iOS 15 is available, search for the "Set Focus" action. From here, you can turn on or off regular Do Not Disturb, or the Sleep version of Do Not Disturb.